# How to wake a PC with a PHP script?

Tags: php, wake-on-lan

By enabling Wake-on-LAN on my PC, I can remotely power it on.

Suppose I want to send the "magic packet" from a PHP script. How would I do this? Would I need to use the cURL functions?

Comment: I don't think so, cURL is for doing HTTP requests, isn't it? Tells us more about that magic packet...

Comment: Oh yeah... I guess raw sockets then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can peek at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wolviaphp/files/ (uses fsockopen() with 'udp://')

Answer (score 0):

I have used WMI in the past, for the remote management of machines running windows.

So WMI from MS or http://www.openwbem.org/ (the open standard) might be what you are looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: My machine isn't running Windows.